# Why I am seeing brick dust on my basement walls?

Tags: basement, brick

So lately I noticed a lot brick dust in my basement walls-should I be concerned? The house is a 100 year row house. 
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dfix.jpg)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6viH.jpg)

Comment: Are the pictures showing a whitewashed parged coat (a layer of mortar) over brick walls?  Or, as is more likely with a circa 1917 home, are the walls concrete?

Answer (score 1):

Of course a photo would help. :)

But sans photo or any further details, my guess is you are seeing [efflorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efflorescence) which is essentially mineral deposits left from the migration of moisture passing through a porous wall (cement, brick, stucco, etc.)

Comment: Efflorescence is always crystalline; usually white (unless stained by ie. iron oxides).

Comment: Yep. Posted my answer prior to photos.

Comment: I know.  Just clarifying, for others, in case they didn't appreciate importance of pics & "brick dust" being brick coloured.  Efflorescence is often the answer when it isn't spalding.

Comment: Soooo... is this normal or should I take some action steps?

Comment: @ecco88 I don't know if what you are showing is efflorescence or not. It's hard to know what I'm actually looking at. We need more details here. That said, if it *is* efflorescence, that's a sign of moisture migrating through the wall. That's somewhat normal in basements.